# AWS ELB: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, clojure, amazon-elb, aws-cloudformation

my cloudformation stack is deployed successfully. I'm trying to deploy a clojure ring app on EC2.

When I access my elastic load balance endpoint at `my-app.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com` I get`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity)`

I confirmed the tomcat was running by sshing into the ec2 and running `ps -afx`

So what could possibly be the problem here?

update: okay so doing a curl request to localhost:8080 returns HTTP 500

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [clj-west.system/servlet-handler servlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Handler returned nil
        at ring.util.servlet$make_service_method$fn__52.invoke(servlet.clj:127)
        at clj_west.servlet$_service.invoke(servlet.clj:1)
        at clj_west.servlet.service(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Check the number of healthy instances on the ELB. Configure a HealthCheck correctly.

Comment: @Shibashis what is the appropriate setting for tomcat7 server? I see them here but no idea if they are right: `Ping Target HTTP:8080/health-check
Timeout 5 seconds
Interval 12 seconds
Unhealthy threshold 3
Healthy threshold 3`

Comment: Can you curl on localhost and check, if the process is listening on 8080?

Comment: Check security groups as well.

Comment: @Shibashis how do I check security group and what am I looking for. I will try the curl

Comment: Go to aws console and check the security grp associated with the instance

Comment: @Shibashis I ssh into my ec2, when I do `curl http://localhost:8080`, it returns HTTP 500 with `java.lang.NullPointerException: Handler returned nil`

Comment: @Shibashis and I'm seeing all the health check requests are returning 500

Comment: HTTP:8080/health-check, there is no such endpoint on your server

Comment: have you deployed any apps in the tomcat

Comment: Reconfigure the elb heathcheck to a valid endpoint. Some url which has http 200 response.

Comment: @Shibashis makes sense. yes I did deploy a WAR file. does this mean I need to create a health-check endpoint in my web app??

Comment: @Shibashis I updated the question with the stack trace.

Comment: Yes that's the best way to configure the healthcheck. If you are using something like springboot. You may have something out of the box.

Comment: @Shibashis I am not sure I just used the cf template from https://github.com/vrivellino/clojure-west-2014-demo, that is from 2014, so maybe the `/health-check` thing is a new change? Not sure why the author didn't include that.

Comment: Just to confirm, the healthcheck is the issue, you can change it temporarily to an tcp check and configure it to check port 8080. That would not need a healthcheck endpoint. If this is the issue, after changing the healthcheck the elb should register the instance.

Comment: @Shibashis so my other endpoints that I created works, so I guess I will just create teh `/health-check` manually. I will try the TCP check

Comment: manually? do you mean configuring the healthcheck on elb

Comment: @Shibashis I just changed the healthcheck to TCP on elb and confirmed it is working!!!!! I am also able to access my endpoints through elb now. So the problem was it was looking for `/health-check` which did not exist. I'm puzzled as to whether the author thought that tomcat provided this endpoint from the get go...

Comment: @Shibashis yes thats correct I mean create the `/health-check` endpoint manually in my web app so that it will return 200. but I guess the TCP thing works beautifully as well

Comment: Yes. I would recommend creating a healthcheck inside the app. The process may continue to listen on the port but the app might be failing because of other reasons. So tcp heathcheck may not be most appropriate.

Comment: @Shibashis yes you are right, gonna do that now! thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion from comments. The issue got resolved by updating the healthcheck on the ELB.